# Statement with no effect (2)

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors

I've been writing the next function and got "statement with no effect" warning on line 1 then "‘nw’ undeclared" warning on the next usues of 'nw'.

```
symbol *newSymbol(char *symbol, int adress, unsigned int xtrnl, unsigned int action) {
    symbol nw; //line 1
    nw.symbol = symbol; //'nw' undeclared....
    nw.adress = adress;
    nw.xtrnl = xtrnl;
    nw.action = action;
    nw.next = NULL;
    return &nw;
}
```

The structure symbol is:

```
typedef struct {
    char *symbol;
    int adress;
    unsigned int xtrnl : 1;
    unsigned int action : 1;
    struct symbol *next;
} symbol;
```

Comment: Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code. Possibly related: `struct symbol *next;` there is no such struct shown - there is a typedef called `symbol` that is a struct but not a `struct symbol`.

Comment: In `symbol nw;` the `symbol` is also a function argument. Keep your variable and type names unique. Just to add to the confusion `struct symbol` contains a field named `symbol`.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to return the address of a local variable.

Comment: You're trying to use `symbol` as both a type name and a variable name (the name of an argument to `newSymbol`).  That's a name conflict.  Pick a different name for one of them.  And as mentioned, you will get undefined behavior if you return the address of a local variable.  Also, shouldn't `adress` be `address`?

Comment: Enable warnings. As a beginner include a warning for shadowing names from an outer scope. A good compiler should provide such an option.

Comment: Thank you all, problems solved! Probably just tierdness mistakes, it is nearly 1am in here right now (:

Comment: warning, if you want to return a pointer to `symbol` then `nw` should be allocated using `malloc` other wise the function should return `struct symbol` not a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

`symbol` is not only a type name, but also a parameter of `newSymbol()`. Additionally, `symbol` is also a field of `symbol`(type). The first letters of type names are usually capitalized to avoid confusion.

So you can change the declaration of the struct to

```
typedef struct symbol
{
    char *symbol;
    int adress;
    unsigned int xtrnl : 1;
    unsigned int action : 1;
    struct symbol *next;
} Symbol;
```

Then define `newSymbol()` as following:

```
symbol *newSymbol(char *aSymbol, int adress, unsigned int xtrnl, unsigned int action)
{
    symbol *nw = malloc(sizeof (Symbol));
    if(!nw)
        return NULL;
    nw -> ymbol = aSymbol;
    nw -> adress = adress;
    nw -> xtrnl = xtrnl;
    nw -> action = action;
    nw -> next = NULL;
    return nw;
}
```

This also avoids the undefined behavior caused by returning a pointer to local variable.